# How do I use variables as selectors in HMTL/ Bootstrap4?

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a `for` loop to build an accordion in Bootstrap, but every time I click the button to expand/ collapse a card, every card expands/ collapses. I think this is due to a shared `id` across all cards, so I want to use the post title as the `id` selector for each card. Here is the code I currently have:

```
  {% for post in blog_posts %}
    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-header" id="header">
          <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" 
          data-target="#body" aria-expanded="false" 
          aria-controls="post: ">
              {{ post.title }}
              <small><p>Posted by {{ post.author }} on 
              {{ post.date_added|date:'D M d, Y H:i' }}</p></small>
          </button>
        </h3>

        <div id="body" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="header"
          data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            {{ post.text|linebreaks }}
            <small>
              <a class="text-dark" href="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post.id %}">
              edit post</a>
            </small>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  {% empty %}
    <p>There are no posts to display.</p>
  {% endfor %}
```

I've tried changing the `h3` id to `{{ post.title }}`, but that doesn't seem to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `id="{{ post.title }}"` what does id look like when you put it?

Answer (score 1):

Example code:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

You need the id's to be unique for each accordion section (otherwise they will all open at once), you could use the post.id for that.

```
{% if blog_posts %}
<div id="accordion">
  {% for post in blog_posts %}
      <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-header" id="header-{{post.id}}">
          <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" 
          data-target="#post-{{post.id}}" aria-expanded="false" 
          aria-controls="post-{{post.id}}">
              {{ post.title }}
              <small><p>Posted by {{ post.author }} on 
              {{ post.date_added|date:'D M d, Y H:i' }}</p></small>
          </button>
        </h3>

        <div id="post-{{post.id}}" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="header-{{post.id}}"
          data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            {{ post.text|linebreaks }}
            <small>
              <a class="text-dark" href="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post.id %}">
              edit post</a>
            </small>
          </div>
      </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% else %}
    <p>There are no posts to display.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use "primary-key-value-only" as HTML id, cause the taint with other models is easy to create and hard to spot. So add a prefix (`post-`), like you did with `aria-labelledby`.

Comment: agreed, I was just about to make that update to the sample.